# jQuery doesn't handle -some- button click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple text-based game using jQuery. There are some locations, player can move there by pressing buttons (simply showing/hiding corresponding HTML divs). While I can move to location "Arena" and back to location "House" freely, I can't go back from location "Shop" anywhere, but code looks ok for me.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qyg5twoL/

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var loc="house";

 $('#house').css('display','');
 $('#shop').css('display','none');
 $('#arena').css('display','none');

 $('#gt-arena').click(function(){
  loc='arena';
  $('#arena').css('display','');
  $('#shop').css('display','none');
  $('#house').css('display','none');
 });

 $('#gt-house').click(function(){
  alert('house');
  loc='house';
  $('#house').css('display','');
  $('#shop').css('display','none');
  $('#arena').css('display','none');
 });

 $('#gt-shop').click(function(){
  alert('shop');
  loc='shop';
  $('#house').css('display','none');
  $('#shop').css('display','');
  $('#arena').css('display','none');
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>jquery problem</title>

<div id="house">
 <h1>Your house</h1>
 <p>This is your house</p>
 <button id="gt-arena">Go to Arena</button>
 <button id="gt-shop">Go to Shop</button>
</div>

<div id="arena">
 <h1>Arena</h1>
 <p>This is the Arena</p>
 <button id="fight">Fight</button>
 <button id="gt-house">Leave Arena</button>
 <button id="gt-shop">Go to Shop</button>
</div>

<div id="shop">
 <h1>Shop</h1>
 <p>For all your shopping needs</p>
 <button id="buy-knife">Buy knife</button>
 <button id="gt-arena">Go to Arena</button>
 <button id="gt-house">Go to House</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Statement**

The problem lies with **id** selector. You have assigned same **id** to multiple elements. **id** is the identification of the element and should be unique. And when added for more than one element, event is binded only with 1 element and ignored for other. That is why once navigated to `house` you are not able to come back.

**Solution**

In place of **id** use **class** selector.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var loc = "house";

   $('#house').css('display', '');
   $('#shop').css('display', 'none');
   $('#arena').css('display', 'none');

   $('.gt-arena').click(function() {
     loc = 'arena';
     $('#arena').css('display', '');
     $('#shop').css('display', 'none');
     $('#house').css('display', 'none');
   });

   $('.gt-house').click(function() {
     alert('house');
     loc = 'house';
     $('#house').css('display', '');
     $('#shop').css('display', 'none');
     $('#arena').css('display', 'none');
   });

   $('.gt-shop').click(function() {
     alert('shop');
     loc = 'shop';
     $('#house').css('display', 'none');
     $('#shop').css('display', '');
     $('#arena').css('display', 'none');
   });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>jquery problem</title>

<div id="house">
  <h1>Your house</h1>
  <p>This is your house</p>
  <button class="gt-arena">Go to Arena</button>
  <button class="gt-shop">Go to Shop</button>
</div>

<div id="arena">
  <h1>Arena</h1>
  <p>This is the Arena</p>
  <button id="fight">Fight</button>
  <button class="gt-house">Leave Arena</button>
  <button class="gt-shop">Go to Shop</button>
</div>

<div id="shop">
  <h1>Shop</h1>
  <p>For all your shopping needs</p>
  <button id="buy-knife">Buy knife</button>
  <button class="gt-arena">Go to Arena</button>
  <button class="gt-house">Go to House</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have more than one same id's. id should be unique for every element in the DOM.

Below code should work for you.

Hope it helps

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var loc="house";

 $('.content').css('display','none');
 $('#house').css('display','');

 $('.gt-arena').click(function(){
  loc='arena';
  $('.content').css('display','none');
  $('#arena').css('display','');
 });

 $('.gt-house').click(function(){
  alert('house');
  loc='house';
  $('.content').css('display','none');
  $('#house').css('display','');
 });

 $('.gt-shop').click(function(){
  alert('shop');
  loc='shop';
  $('.content').css('display','none');
  $('#shop').css('display','');
 });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>jquery problem</title>

<div id="house" class="content">
 <h1>Your house</h1>
 <p>This is your house</p>
 <button class="gt-arena">Go to Arena</button>
 <button class="gt-shop">Go to Shop</button>
</div>

<div id="arena" class="content">
 <h1>Arena</h1>
 <p>This is the Arena</p>
 <button class="fight">Fight</button>
 <button class="gt-house">Leave Arena</button>
 <button class="gt-shop">Go to Shop</button>
</div>

<div id="shop" class="content">
 <h1>Shop</h1>
 <p>For all your shopping needs</p>
 <button class="buy-knife">Buy knife</button>
 <button class="gt-arena">Go to Arena</button>
 <button class="gt-house">Go to House</button>
</div>
```